# jQuery change div background-image with fadeIn/Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a fadeIn/Out effect on a site I created (edit: site url deleted)

Everything works great except when you click on one of the colors in the color palette, it replaces the image with no effect.

This is the small script I wrote, which is triggered onclick on one of the colors.

```
function changeImage(newColor) {

    //var previousImage = $('#image-holder').css("background-image");

    $('#image-holder').css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')");
};
```

I tried playing with `$('#image-holder').fadeOut(1500)` and then `$('#image-holder').fadeIn(1500)` but it acts funny... it double fades the image.

```
$('#image-holder').css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')").fadeOut(function(){$(this).fadeIn()});
```

What I would like to achieve is onclick on a color box, the current background image will fadeout while the new background image will fade in.

I know it's easier to achieve that if I'd used two `<img src="" />` and switch their display/visibility but I unfortunately I can't alter the HTML that much so I'm looking for a jQuery based solution.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

```
var image = $('#image-holder');
    image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
        image.css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')");
        image.fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this, but this fades the whole container in and out, not only the backgroud image. This is undesirable in most cases.

Answer (score 25):

This was the only reasonable thing I found to fade a background image.

```
<div id="foo">
  <!-- some content here -->
</div>
```

Your CSS; now enhanced with [CSS3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

```
#foo {
  background-image: url('a.jpg');
  transition: background 1s linear;
}
```

Now swap out the background

```
$("#foo").css("background-image", "url(b.jpg)");
```

Or do it with native javascript

```
document.querySelector("#foo").style.backgroundImage = "url(b.jpg)";
```

Voilà, it fades!

---

**Obvious disclaimer:** if your browser doesn't support the CSS3 `transition` property, this won't work.

Comment: best answer :) why use jquery when you can just add one line of css :D

Comment: Not a great answer actually I would say since this would only work in Chrome, Safari, Opera. Firefox 33 and IE11 do not yet support this. Background-image transitions are not part of CSS3 animations unfortunately so it could be a while.

Comment: @Trevor, background animations are clearly a part of CSS3. I would also argue that supporting a superfluous effect in an old browser is a fool's errand.

Comment: Clearly part of CSS3, how so? As per W3C - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties  As you can see background-images are not included in the list of properties, which likely explains why IE and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052) do no support it. It's a bummer but it's true.

Comment: @naomik its a little late but it still works like a charm, thanks a lot.

Comment: But if I have only one image?

Answer (score 4):

```
var currentBackground = 0;

var backgrounds = [];

backgrounds[0] = 'images/BasePic1.jpg';

backgrounds[1] = 'images/BasePic2.jpg';

backgrounds[2] = 'images/BasePic3.jpg';

backgrounds[3] = 'images/BasePic4.jpg';

backgrounds[4] = 'images/BasePic5.jpg';

function changeBackground() {

    currentBackground++;

    if(currentBackground > 4) currentBackground = 0;

    $('#image-holder').fadeOut(1500,function() {
        $('#image-holder').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('#image-holder').fadeIn(1500);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(changeBackground, 5000);  

});
```

Comment: this works but fades out everything, including the child elements with the content. is it possible fade out the ONLY background images on parent element?

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions just fade in the element, rather than the background. This means that your information is hidden while the background is loading, which is more than often not what you want.

I have written the following solution, which works by taking your background image and adding it as an image to the element. It then fades in when it has loaded while all the time keeping your child elements visible.

It also adds a preloading gif which disappears when it loads. You may need to test with a larger image to see this in action.

Code and fiddle/snippet below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.Loader').each(function(index, el) {

    var sBG = jQuery(this).css('background-image');
    sBG = sBG.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');

    jQuery(this).prepend('<img src="' + sBG + '" id="tmp_' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + '" class="BGImage" />');
    jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url("http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif")');

    jQuery(".BGImage:not(.processed)").each(function() {
      this.onload = function() {

        var oElement = jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('tmp_', ''));
        jQuery('#' + jQuery(oElement).attr('id')).css('background-image', 'none');
        oElement.removeClass('Loader');
        jQuery(this).fadeIn(3000);

      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.Loader {

  background-position: center;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  transition: background 0.5s linear;

}

.BGImage {

  position: absolute;

  z-index: -1;

  display: none;

}

#Test {

  height: 300px;

  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMa7lFP0VdTl63KgPAOotSies-YQ3qSslOuXWE6FnFxJ_EfF7tsA);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Test" class="Loader">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, did the same thing.  This is viable and cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery to inject the markup that you need?

```
var $image_holder = $('#imageHolder'),
    $carousel_container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'carousel_container'),
    images = ['first.jpg', 'second.jpg', 'third.jpg'];

for ( var i=0; i<images.length; i++ )
{
    $('<img/>').attr('src', images[i]).appendTo($carousel_container);
}

$carousel_container.insertAfter($image_holder);
$image_holder.hide();
```

Answer (score -3):

You might want to try something like this

Replace

`$('#image-holder').css("background", "url('images/design-" + newColor + ".jpg')");`

with

`$('#image-holder').animate({background : url('images/design-' + newColor + '.jpg') }, 3000);`

Adjust the `3000` as necessary to increase the amount of time in the animation.

*Totally untested*

Comment: seems like a possible solution but it won't even change the image... maybe the syntax is wrong? I'll look in to it.

Comment: It should change the image if you are passing it through the function parameter `changeImage(newColor)`.

Comment: I am.. tested with alert.. It gets the right color but the image won't change.. tried playing with the syntax but nothing.

Comment: @JasonGennaro : `{background : url('images/design-' + newColor + '.jpg') }` will execute the function `url(...)` !!!