# Adding transition effect to a current script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code to change the background pic from a url php output. can someone please help me integrating a picture transition effect to this script.

```
setInterval(function fetchImage() {

        $.get("test.php", function(data){ // "data" is whatever your php script returns
            //console.log(data); // for debugging your php response
            var imageString = 'url(' + data + ') no-repeat'; // Build your background css string
            $('td#banner').css('background',imageString); // assign the value of imageString to the td's background css property
        });

    }, 2000);

<td class="banner" id="banner">
</td>
```

Comment: what error are you getting....also is `data` defined? do `if(data){ var imageString ....}`

Comment: Current Script...   the script works fine I need to add a fade transition effect.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`$.fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) It seems you have to make sure you set your element to `display: none`

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/ZpPPk/3/

```
$('td#banner').css({
    'background-image': 'url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png)',
    display: 'none'
}).fadeIn(1000);
```

If you want the background image to fade in, but not the foreground, that's actually kind of hard. You can't use `background-image`, you'll have to layer a div behind it and call `$.fadeIn` on that

Comment: Im really noob at this can you please give me a full example with the code ill already posted

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand, just add `.fadeIn()` at the end of your call to `$('td#banner').css('background', imageString)` I prefer not to post full examples, I am not going to do it for you, I'm  going to show you what can be done. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610973/jquery-change-div-background-image-with-fadein-out and

Comment: I got that part, I just don't know to make the div work

Comment: How to make the div work??? Please explain yourself more clearly. Are you saying what I suggested is not good enough and you want to use the layering of divs instead? Like I mentioned in my question, that can be very tricky and I can't afford to take the time to figure out exactly what you need. You have to at least give it a shot before you ask someone to do it for you. Maybe ask a new question... But try before you ask...

Comment: (`$('div#banner').css('background',imageString).fadeIn(4000)`)

Comment: <div id="banner" class="banner" >
</div>

Comment: `"Pasting a bunch of code" != "explaining yourself clearly"` :)

Comment: the picture changes normally but I have 0 transition effect

Comment: .fadeIn() is added to the end. and still don't works

Comment: You have to make the div not visible first, it seems. Check out the example I linked to.